# Is there another way to ask for credentials in Powershell but Get-Credential?

Tags: powershell, credentials

My Powershell Script asks for credentials using the following syntax, and it works all right:

`$credentials = (Get-Credential -Message "Enter Password")`

But the problem is that the window that pops to enter the user name and password has very little space and it is uncomfortable for the user to enter large user names (large server name backslash large user names), and that windows does not allow resizing.

I would like to give my users the ability to enter usernames and passwords in another bigger window.
Any Idea?

Comment: Probably you would have to design a custom form yourself. It's not that hard to do.

Comment: take a look at using `Read-Host` to get secure strings. that would let you work in the entire console ... [*grin*]

Comment: Take a look at the output of the cmdlet in PowerShell  v7.xx! It does not open a graphical pop up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had something similar to this so I thought why not share it. Give it a try, it does not look as pretty as `Get-Credential` but you can resize it.

It will return a `PSCredential` object, same as `Get-Credential`.
The `OK` button only becomes `Enabled` if **Username** and **Password** have text.

[image: example]

```bash
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Drawing

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms, System.Drawing
Add-Type -TypeDefinition '
public class DPIAware {
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();
}
'

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
[void] [DPIAware]::SetProcessDPIAware()

function Get-CustomCredential {
    [Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

    #$DPI    = [math]::round([dpi]::scaling(), 2) * 100
    $bounds = [Screen]::PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea
    #$bounds.Width  = $bounds.Width / 100 * $DPI
    #$bounds.Height = $bounds.Height / 100 * $DPI

    $mainForm = [Form]@{
        StartPosition   = 'CenterScreen'
        FormBorderStyle = 'Sizable'
        Text            = 'Get Custom Credential'
        WindowState     = 'Normal'
        KeyPreview      = $true
        Font            = [Font]::new('Calibri', 11, [FontStyle]::Regular)
        Icon            = [Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon((Get-Process -Id $PID).Path)
        MinimumSize     = [Size]::new($bounds.Width / 3.5, $bounds.Height / 4)
        MaximumSize     = [Size]::new($bounds.Width, $bounds.Height / 4)
        MaximizeBox     = $false
    }
    $mainForm.Size = $mainForm.MinimumSize

    $credentialMsg = [Label]@{
        Location   = [Point]::new(10, 10)
        Size       = [Size]::new($mainForm.Width - 30, 30)
        Text       = 'Supply values for the following parameters:'
    }
    $mainForm.Controls.Add($credentialMsg)

    $userLbl = [Label]@{
        Location = [Point]::new(10, 60)
        Size     = [Size]::new(120, 30)
        Text     = 'Username'
    }
    $mainForm.Controls.Add($userLbl)

    $userTxtBox = [TextBox]@{
        Location = [Point]::new($userLbl.Width + 10, 60)
        Size     = [Size]::new($mainForm.Width - 160, 60)
    }
    $mainForm.Controls.Add($userTxtBox)

    $passwordLbl = [Label]@{
        Location = [Point]::new(10, $userLbl.Location.Y + 40)
        Size     = [Size]::new(120, 30)
        Text     = 'Password'
    }
    $mainForm.Controls.Add($passwordLbl)

    $passwordTxtBox = [TextBox]@{
        Location              = [Point]::new($passwordLbl.Width + 10, $userTxtBox.Location.Y + 40)
        Size                  = [Size]::new($mainForm.Width - 160, 60)
        UseSystemPasswordChar = $true
        Anchor                = 'top, left'
    }
    $mainForm.Controls.Add($passwordTxtBox)

    $cancelBtn = [Button]@{
        Location = [Point]::new($mainForm.Width - 130, $passwordTxtBox.Location.Y + 50)
        Size     = [Size]::new(100, 45)
        Text     = '&Cancel'
        Anchor   = 'right, bottom'
    }
    $cancelBtn.Add_Click({
        $mainForm.DialogResult = 'Cancel'
    })
    $mainForm.Controls.Add($cancelBtn)

    $okBtn = [Button]@{
        Location = [Size]::new($cancelBtn.Location.X - $cancelBtn.Width - 5, $passwordTxtBox.Location.Y + 50)
        Size     = $cancelBtn.Size
        Text     = '&OK'
        Anchor   = $cancelBtn.Anchor
        Enabled  = $false
    }
    $okBtn.Add_Click({
        $mainForm.DialogResult = 'OK'
    })
    $mainForm.Controls.Add($okBtn)

    $okBtnEnableEvent = {
        if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($userTxtBox.Text) -or [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($passwordTxtBox.Text)) {
            $okBtn.Enabled = $false
            return
        }
        $okBtn.Enabled = $True

    }
    $userTxtBox.Add_TextChanged($okBtnEnableEvent)
    $passwordTxtBox.Add_Textchanged($okBtnEnableEvent)

    $mainForm.Add_Resize({
        $userTxtBox.Size     = [Size]::new($this.Width - 160, 60)
        $passwordTxtBox.Size = [Size]::new($this.Width - 160, 60)
    })
    $mainForm.AcceptButton = $okBtn
    $mainForm.CancelButton = $cancelBtn
    $mainForm.Add_Shown({ $this.Activate() })

    if('OK' -eq $mainForm.ShowDialog()) {
        $passw = ConvertTo-SecureString $passwordTxtBox.Text.Trim() -AsPlainText -Force
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new($userTxtBox.Text.Trim(), $passw)
    }

    $mainForm.Dispose()
}

$creds = Get-CustomCredential
```

Props to [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) for his nice feedback and help with code improvements.

Comment: Thank you very much @SantiagoSquerzon for your so complete code. It will help me not only with this problema but as a template to generate a lot more forms.. Thank You!!

Comment: @MundoPeter no problem, happy to help :)

Comment: Nicely done; a few tips: `System.Drawing` doesn't need to be loaded separately, and instead of `[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')` it's better to use `Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms`. If you also want it to work in PowerShell Core, replace `[System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("$PSHOME\PowerShell.exe")` with `[System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon((Get-Process -Id $PID).Path)`.

Comment: You can make do without OK/Cancel button events as follows: `$okBtn.DialogResult = 'OK'` and `$cancelBtn.DialogResult = 'Cancel'`, combined with `$mainForm.AcceptButton = $okBtn` and `$mainForm.CancelButton = $cancelBtn`. This also implicitly enables ESC / Enter support.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks so much for the feedback, really appreciate feedback on WinForms. I _think_ I didn't miss anything. I also added DPI awareness which is something I cracked my head trying to find when I needed it (not sure whose code is it but I think it's worth sharing that too, also not sure if there is something like that on PS Code instead of C#). I have 2 questions if you don't mind, `AcceptButton` and `CancelButton` should be binded to the form __after__ both objects have been created right? And, do you see a more elegant way of returning the `PSCredential` but a script scoped variable?

Comment: Thanks for the DPI code; I've never had to deal with it, but it sounds like in v4.7+ .NET helper methods are now available - see [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms). Yes, you need to create the button control first, and then assign them to the form's `.AcceptButton` and `.CancelButton` properties. I wouldn't create the credential object in an _event handler_, I'd check the `.ShowDialog()` result for `'OK'` and create the object then (see next comment).

Comment: `if ('OK' -eq $mainForm.ShowDialog()) {
  # Construct and output a PSCredential instance.
  [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new(
    $userTxtBox.Text.Trim(),
    (ConvertTo-SecureString $passwordTxtBox.Text.Trim() -AsPlainText -Force)
  )
}
$mainForm.Dispose()
`

Comment: @mklement0 it makes total sense to create the `PS credential` outside the click event, not sure why I didn't see that. On a side note, I'm not sure how to get `Control.DeviceDpi Property` to work on PowerShell. In any case, thanks so much for the feedback, really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @SantiagoSquarzon; my pleasure. Again, my knowledge is superficial with respect to the DPI stuff, but `Form` instances inherit from `Control` too, so you should be able to make calls such as `$mainForm.LogicalToDeviceUnits(...)`. I forgot to mention that your `Add-Type` call needs tweaking for PowerShell _Core_: `$refAssemblies = @('System.Drawing')
if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 6) { $refAssemblies += 'System.Drawing.Common' } Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $refAssemblies -IgnoreWarnings -WarningAction Ignore -TypeDefinition ...`