# Disable high DPI scaling

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, winapi

I want to get correct data from my code when screen scaling is enabled. So i'm using [SetProcessDPIAware()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setprocessdpiaware) function:

```
using namespace System.Windows.Forms

Clear-Host
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -Name User32 -Namespace W32 '
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();'


[Cursor]::Position | Write-Host
[Screen]::PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size | Write-Host
[SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize | Write-Host

[W32.User32]::SetProcessDPIAware()

[Cursor]::Position | Write-Host
[Screen]::PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size | Write-Host
[SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize | Write-Host
```

Output:

```
{X=630,Y=313}             # ❌ incorrect data
{Width=2048, Height=864}  # ❌ incorrect data
{Width=2048, Height=864}  # ❌ incorrect data
True
{X=788,Y=391}             # ✔️ data became correct
{Width=2048, Height=864}  # ❌ still incorrect data
{Width=2560, Height=1080} # ✔️ data became correct
```

The same situation with c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 
public class Class1
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        Console.WriteLine(Cursor.Position);
        Console.WriteLine(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
        Console.WriteLine(SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize);

        Console.WriteLine(SetProcessDPIAware());

        Console.WriteLine(Cursor.Position);
        Console.WriteLine(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
        Console.WriteLine(SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize);
    }
}
```

So is this a bug of `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds` or i have to do something else to get correct data from this property?

*And if the only way is to use the `SystemInformation` class, then how do I get data about the second monitor, not only about the Primary one?*

**OR**
Is there a way to set [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tkJk.jpg) setting for powershell.exe / powershell_ise.exe ?

Comment: If you need per-monitor DPI awareness, setting DPI awareness to `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_SYSTEM_AWARE` won't cut it.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use and works for me:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;

public class DPI
{  
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int nIndex);

    public enum DeviceCap
    {
        VERTRES = 10,
        DESKTOPVERTRES = 117
    } 

    public static float scaling()
    {
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
        IntPtr desktop = g.GetHdc();
        int LogicalScreenHeight = GetDeviceCaps(desktop, (int)DeviceCap.VERTRES);
        int PhysicalScreenHeight = GetDeviceCaps(desktop, (int)DeviceCap.DESKTOPVERTRES);

        return (float)PhysicalScreenHeight / (float)LogicalScreenHeight;
    }
}
'@ -ReferencedAssemblies System.Drawing -IgnoreWarnings -WarningAction Ignore
```

Then you can call this class and get the DPI like:

```
$DPI = [math]::round([dpi]::scaling(), 2) * 100
$bounds = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea
$bounds.Width = ($bounds.Width / 100) * $DPI
$bounds.Height = ($bounds.Height / 100) * $DPI
```

And lastly, always use relative sizes like:

```
$form.Size = [System.Drawing.Size]::new(($bounds.Width / X),($bounds.Height / X))
```

```
$form.Add_Resize({
    $txtBox.Size = [System.Drawing.Size]::new(($this.Width - X), XX)
})
```

And so on, where `X` can be an `int` or `double`.

- [Source for the class](https://hinchley.net/articles/get-the-scaling-rate-of-a-display-using-powershell/). I'm not sure if this is the OP as I have seen the same code posted on different sites.
- Example of DPI Aware form: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68240960/15339544

---

- Left Monitor: 1920x1080 - 175% Scaling
- Right Monitor: 1920x1080 - 100% Scaling

[image: 2mons]

Comment: How well does this work if you have different DPI settings for different display devices?

Comment: @IInspectable I'm honestly not sure, what I do know is that the class will return the DPI value of the display device where the class was loaded and I'm using `PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea` to set `$bounds` because of this too. As for, how it works when using 2 different DPI settings, I think Windows is taking care of this tho I might be wrong (see my edit with the gif)

Comment: *"the DPI value of the display device where the class was loaded"* - That doesn't make any sense. Types aren't activated on display devices. *"when using 2 different DPI settings, I think Windows is taking care of this"* - How is that supposed to work? It's not like a call to `GetDeviceCaps` would magically return different values. It returns a single value, and since classes don't live on display devices, then that's that. I doubt there's anything useful in this proposed answer.

Comment: @IInspectable you're right. the class is always returning the DPI of the primary display device. I posted this because it's what's work for me personally, I've never claimed to be an expert. If you have a working solution, please post it as answer.