# Powershell: How can i get the primary screen resolution of a logged in user?

Tags: windows, powershell, display, screen-resolution

Our current scenario is this:

We have more than 80 tablet computers (running Windows 10) in our network that run under the same user (*DefaultUser*). In order to verify that the display settings are correctly set, we would like to use a powershell script to automatically check the used resolution remotely with a support user account.

So far, we know how to get the primary screen resolution for the user under which the script gets executed (which is rather easy):

```
  // get primary screen width
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
  [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width   // height accordingly
```

In case we execute this script on one of the tablets using the support account, we get the primary screen resolution for the support account user - but not for the desired user *DefaultUser*.

**How can we get the resolution for the *DefaultUser*?**

The only solution that easily comes to my mind is a rather ugly thing:
Using the windows task scheduler i could create a task that executes the script (under the defaultUser) to get the screen resolution and write the result(s) into a file that can be accessed by the support user account. But i am looking for something more elegant.

Comment: Is DefaultUser logged in? Is the support user running as admin or system?

Comment: @Anders : yes, the DefaultUser is logged in. The support user is running with system privileges.

Comment: Did you already try [`runas.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11))?

Comment: @stackprotector : No. How would a command to call a powershell script look like to return the resolution. Can you provide a fully working solution?

Comment: Couldn't you get the settings from the registry at `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration\<whatever the internal display shows up as>\00\00` under the `ActiveSize.cx` and `ActiveSize.cy` values?

Comment: I'm not sure this question can be answered. To the best of my knowledge, Windows *does not* support per-user resolution settings. It's only stored at the system level (at the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE hive path mentioned above or at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Hardware Profiles/Current/System/CurrentControlSet/Video/`). That's why software like "Carroll" exists which provides that functionality.

Comment: I think what you might be looking for is the inline c# used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68240960/15339544)

Comment: @Thariama I cannot reproduce different users having different resolutions. If I change the resolution of one user, it also changes the resolution for the other (logged on) user. So I back Bacon Bits comment. Can you clarify on how to reproduce this? It might be that your _DefaultUser_ uses a logon script to set the resolution or another software. Or that your users use different scales (see Cpt. Whales answer) instead of different resolutions. Can you clarify your current situation?

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use CIM or WMI to get from point a to b.

CIM_VideoController is the class that would contain the resolution.

Using PowerShell Core:

```
Get-CimInstance CIM_VideoController | Select SystemName, CurrentHorizontalResolution, CurrentVerticalResolution
```

Using Windows PowerShell:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_VideoController | Select SystemName, CurrentHorizontalResolution, CurrentVerticalResolution
```

You should be able to open the proper ports to use either of these options remotely (though you could also probably get away with using Invoke-Command to run them, as long as you use CredSSP or Kerberos Delegation to take the 2nd hop  problem into account).

Comment: These command work, but yields the resolution for the currently active user only. Is there a way to get the resolution for another logged-in user (defaultUser)?

Comment: PowerShell does not support kerberos double hop scenarios. For this CredSSP is available or you have to passover the credentials into the remote session.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for the screen scaling values, based on your code checking the `PrimaryScreen` values:

```
# My monitor resolution is 3000x2000
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
# [Screen] returns screen size AFTER scaling (200% here)
[System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
1000
# [SystemInformation] returns the hardware screen resolution (applies to all users)
[System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VirtualScreen.Height
2000
```

Scaling **can** be set on a per-user basis, though there is a machine-wide "Default" setting. Screen scaling is weird, and gets done differently depending on what version of windows you have. Here's how it works in Windows 10 at least.

You can check the current values like so:

```sh
# AllUsers setting, which shows as (default)
Get-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics" | fl AppliedDPI  
# User's current scaling setting (I use a * instead of the per-monitor ID)
Get-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\PerMonitorSettings\*" | fl DpiValue
```

```
# AppliedDPI shows the "Default" scaling setting on a system level like:
96  : 100% 
120 : 125% 
144 : 150% 
192 : 200%  (my default)

# DpiValue shows how many steps up or down the current user's scaling setting is. For example on my machine:
#250%
DpiValue : 2           # +2
#200% (default)
DpiValue : 0
#150%
DpiValue : 4294967294  # -1
#100%
DpiValue : 4294967292  # -3
```

---

Finding and overriding scaling for other user profiles is pretty involved, but has been done by other people. I found [this script](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/176533-overriding-windows-display-scale) and usage details by user [romaliceishimwe2](https://community.spiceworks.com/people/romaliceishimwe2). I have not tested, but it does show how to look at and change other users' profiles:

```
#First we configure the default, later we will configure any existing users.
#Load the ntuser.dat of the default user
REG LOAD HKU\Default_User C:\users\default\ntuser.dat
#Assign new registry keys
New-ItemProperty -path registry::"HKU\Default_User\Control Panel\Desktop" -Name LogPixels -Value 120 -Type DWord
New-ItemProperty -path registry::"HKU\Default_User\Control Panel\Desktop" -Name Win8DpiScaling -Value 1 -Type DWord
#unload default user ntuser.dat
REG UNLOAD HKU\Default_User

#Here we configure any eixting users
# Regex pattern for SIDs
$PatternSID = 'S-1-5-21-\d+-\d+\-\d+\-\d+$'

# Get Username, SID, and location of ntuser.dat for all users
$ProfileList = gp 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*' | Where-Object {$_.PSChildName -match $PatternSID} | 
    Select  @{name="SID";expression={$_.PSChildName}}, 
            @{name="UserHive";expression={"$($_.ProfileImagePath)\ntuser.dat"}}, 
            @{name="Username";expression={$_.ProfileImagePath -replace '^(.*[\\\/])', ''}}

# Get all user SIDs found in HKEY_USERS (ntuder.dat files that are loaded)
$LoadedHives = gci Registry::HKEY_USERS | ? {$_.PSChildname -match $PatternSID} | Select @{name="SID";expression={$_.PSChildName}}

# Get all users that are not currently logged
$UnloadedHives = Compare-Object $ProfileList.SID $LoadedHives.SID | Select @{name="SID";expression={$_.InputObject}}, UserHive, Username

# Loop through each profile on the machine
Foreach ($item in $ProfileList) {
    # Load User ntuser.dat if it's not already loaded
    IF ($item.SID -in $UnloadedHives.SID) {
        reg load HKU\$($Item.SID) $($Item.UserHive) | Out-Null
    }


   #####################################################################
    # This is where you can read/modify a users portion of the registry 

    "{0}" -f $($item.Username) | Write-Output
        New-ItemProperty -path registry::"HKU\$($Item.SID)\Control Panel\Desktop" -Name LogPixels -Value 120 -Type DWord -force
        New-ItemProperty -path registry::"HKU\$($Item.SID)\Control Panel\Desktop" -Name Win8DpiScaling -Value 1 -Type DWord -force

    #####################################################################

    # Unload ntuser.dat        
    IF ($item.SID -in $UnloadedHives.SID) {
        ### Garbage collection and closing of ntuser.dat ###
        [gc]::Collect()
        reg unload HKU\$($Item.SID) | Out-Null
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that is not exactly what i am looking for